# Breaking Ruby class for DRY

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I have some classes like these:

```
class Word
  def initialize (file_name)
    load_file(file_name)
  end

  def pick_first_word(score)
    #get first word
  end

  private
  def load_file(file_name)
    #load the file
  end
end


class MyClass < SomeOther
  def initialize (file_name)
    @word = Word.new(file_name)
  end
  def pick
    @word.pick_first_word
  end
  #some other code
end

dosomething = MyClass.new("words.txt")
dosomethingelse = MyClass.new("movies.txt")
```

So I have a class for `Word` that reads in a file and picks first word. Just like that I want to have another class, say `Movies`, that will have its own implementation of `load_file` and `pick_first_word`. I want this controlled by the type of file that I send to `MyClass`.

**Question**

What is a good way to change the `initialize` method in `MyClass` so that it initiates the correct class based on the type of file I send. I can do it by if/else on the file name but that doesn't seem very scalable.

Is there a better way to do this than changing `initialize` method for `MyClass` to this?

```
  def initialize (file_name)
    if (file_name == "word.txt")
      @word = Word.new(file_name)
    else
      @word = Movie.new(file_name)
  end
```

This implementation doesn't seem very scalable.

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for the "Strategy" design pattern: http://www.codercaste.com/2011/09/the-strategy-design-pattern-in-ruby/

Comment: Is there a way to detect the difference from the file itself?

Comment: no, not really. But I'm open to passing something else along with the file name if that helps. File name can stay inside the actual class even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all a matter of tradeoffs -- in this case, you want just enough complexity to handle a reasonable number of cases.

If there are only two options, I think that if statement looks just fine. A ['case' statement](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) (aka a switch statement) can be DRYer, and you may want to explicitly say "movie.txt", e.g.

```
@word = (case file_name
  when "word.txt"
    Word
  when "movie.txt"
    Movie
  else
    raise "Unknown file name #{file_name}"
  end).new(file_name)
```

or extract a `class_for_file_name` method if you don't like putting a case statement in parens, even though it's pretty fun.

If your set of polymorphic classes gets bigger, you might get more mileage out of a lookup table:

```
class_for_file_name = {
    "word.txt" => Word, 
    "movie.txt" => Movie, 
    "sandwich.txt" => Sandwich,
}
@word = class_for_file_name[file_name].new(file_name)
```

And of course, maybe you're oversimplifying and you really want to switch on the file *extension*, not the file *name*, which you could get with `File.extname(file_name)`.

You could also get even fancier and ask each concrete class whether it handles this file name; this feels more OO -- it puts the knowledge about foos inside the Foo class -- but is arguably more complicated:

```
class Word
  def self.good_for? file_name
    file_name == "word.txt"
  end
end

class Movie
  def self.good_for? file_name
    file_name == "movie.txt"
  end
end

...

def class_for_file_name file_name
  [Word, Movie].detect{|k| k.good_for? file_name}
end
```

BTW this problem more or less fits the design pattern called [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern); you may want to look it up and see if any of its analyses inspire you.

Answer (score -1):

Try the FileMagic library.

```
gem install ruby-filemagic
```

Example:

```
require 'filemagic'
type = FileMagic.new.file file_name
```